# Get signal from different PC sound card channels using Python

Tags: python, audio, soundcard

I want to know about how to get signal from different channels PC sound card using Python.
In one channel, I want to get a simple signal like sine wave and from another, I want to get a square wave.

I know that I can get signal using pyaudio like

```
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(
    format=FORMAT, 
    channels=CHANNELS, 
    rate=RATE, input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK) #I get one signal
```

But using this method I can only get one signal at a time (stream), and I would need to get two simultaneous signals (two "stream").

Comment: So you mean record 2 channels at once? or open up access to 2 seperate sound cards at once?

Comment: I want to receive different signals from 2 channels at once, by the same sound card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve splitting the list in two and changing `CHANNELS=2`

if `signal` is the list I get from the pyaudio function,
`signal[::2]` is a channel and `signal[1::2`] is another.

There's a exemple below:

```
sinal = np.frombuffer(stream.read(CHUNK, exception_on_overflow=False), np.int16)
sinal[::2] #from channel 1 for exemple
sinal[1::2] #from channel 2 for exemple
```

Answer (score 0):

< /Hey >

It looks like your only issue here is you are only specifying one channel!

```
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1 # Change this to 2 !!!
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(
    format=FORMAT, 
    channels=CHANNELS, 
    rate=RATE, input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK) #I get one signal
```

Just change the line where you specify the channels to :

```
CHANNELS = 2
```

Then you will receive 2 channels of audio :-)

You can increase this number more to record more channels at once if your audio interface has enough inputs.

**Edit 1:**

This will let you read 2 streams of incoming audio for example:

```
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
print "finished recording"
```

Then your `data` (2 arrays, your 2 channel inputs) will be stored in the `frames` array.

For a full 2 channel example see git hosted Python code [here](https://gist.github.com/mabdrabo/8678538).

Comment: OK thanks I'll get these two signals at once on different channels. But will these two signs be in the same stream? I do not know if it would work for me. Because my goal is to receive these signals and then multiply them. For example sin (xt) X cos (xt). So I thought about receiving them in different streams.

Comment: Hey @juniorcl ! I've updated my answer to explain a bit more and provided a full example link. You can manipulate each channel separately with this technique as you desire. If this is correct then let me know and mark it so!

Comment: Thanks again. So, will the list have two signs inside it? The first half of the list would be the signal obtained by one channel and the other half of the list will be the another signal?